# Get cart Items by customer ID

Tags: magento2, addtocart, cart-items

I want cart items like product ids, product names of particular customer id.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
 $quote= $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->loadByCustomer($c‌​ustomerId); 
 $quoteItems=$quote->getAllVisibleItems();
 foreach($quoteItems as $oneItem){
 //$oneItem->getName();
 //$oneItem->getProductId();
 }
```

Comment: This is Magento 2 question, not Magento 1.

Comment: @ToanNguyen I have edited my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a block and a template file, so try with

> app/code/MYCOMPANY/EXTENSION/Block/Stackoverflow.php

```
protected $checkoutSession;    

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getCheckoutSession()
{
    return $this->_checkoutSession;
}
```

> app/design/MYCOMPANY_THEME/something/here/Stackoverflow.phtml

```
// Get all items in cart

$quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote()->loadByCustomer($customerId);
$items = $quote->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}

// Get total items and total quantity in cart

$totalItems = $quote->getItemsCount();
$totalQuantity = $quote->getItemsQty();

//Get subtotal and grand total price of cart

$subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();

//Get billing and shipping addresses

$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
```