# magento 2 programatically get cart items of customer using customer id?

Tags: magento2, cart, customer-account, customer-session

```
protected $quoteFactory;

protected $quoteModel;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote $quoteModel
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->quoteModel=$quoteModel;
    ....

}     
$customerId=8;
     $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
     $customerQuote=$this->quoteModel->loadByCustomerId($quote,$customerId);
 // where `$customerId` is your `customer id`
     $items=$customerQuote->getAllItems();
     print_r($items);
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178715/get-cart-items-by-customer-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    ....

}

$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customer);
$items=$quote->getAllItems();
```

Where `$customer` is customer object (`Magento\Customer\Model\Customer`)

---

**EDIT**

If you don't have `customer` object then you can also load by `customer id` by this way,

```
protected $quoteFactory;

protected $quoteModel;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote $quoteModel
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->quoteModel=$quoteModel;
    ....

}

$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
$customerQuote=$this->quoteModel->loadByCustomerId($quote,$customerId); // where `$customerId` is your `customer id`
$items=$customerQuote->getAllItems();
```

Comment: How can i load cart by customer id?

Comment: See my edit :) @srg

Comment: when i try the above code am getting error response: Call to undefined method Magento\\Quote\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Quote::getAllItems()'

Comment: Please post your error @srg

Comment: this is my error   :   "Fatal Error: 'Call to undefined method Magento\\Quote\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Quote::getAllItems()'

Comment: please post your full code here I am not sure why It gives error at your side @srg

Comment: protected $quoteFactory;

protected $quoteModel;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote $quoteModel
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->quoteModel=$quoteModel;
    ....
}$customerId=8;
     $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
     $customerQuote=$this->quoteModel->loadByCustomerId($quote,$customerId);
     $items=$customerQuote->getAllItems();
     print_r($items);

Comment: please edit your question here i can not see in proper way @srg

Comment: @ Keyur Shah  i have edited the question is it clear for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerId);
```

Is deprecated. Use `CartRepositoryInterface`:

```
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * @var CartRepositoryInterface
 */
protected CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository
) {
    ...
    $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
}

public function getCartData($customerId)
{
    $cart = $this->cartRepository->getForCustomer($customer->getId());
    $items = $cart->getItems();
}
```

Comment: Wrap the getForCustomer() in a try statement for the  \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ............................................
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    ............................................
) {
    ............................................
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    ............................................
}

public function getCartData($customerId)
{
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerId);
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```