# Magento 2.3: get cart items inside the cron file

Tags: magento2, cart, session, quote, crontab

I want to get current quote data for cronjob in `cron/run.php` But my code it's not working.

Magento2 version is CE 2.2.6. Here is my code

```
<?php 
namespace ABC\Abandon\Cron;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
class Run 
{
    protected $logger;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
){
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function execute()
    {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cartObj = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
    $quoteId = $cartObj->getQuote()->getId();
    $itemsArray = $cartObj->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    foreach($itemsArray as $item) 
    {
        $productName[] = $item->getName();
    }
    if(is_array($productName)){
        $productNames .= implode(';',$productName);
    }
        $abdata['productNames'] = $productNames;
        $abdata['quoteid'] = $quoteId;
        return $abdata;
    }
}
```

I am not able to get cart session data inside the cron `run.php` file.

any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I think code working fine. Please check your cron

Comment: @ARUNPRABAKARANM cron is working fine. Only the problem is with the cart session. I am not able to GET cart data in cron run.php file.

Comment: Kindly check my code

Comment: You can not get the current quote from cron, you will need to load quote by customer id.

Comment: @AshishViradiya do you have any reference for this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178717/62614